How to get the pdf link using python selenium
I am trying to find the pdf link from this site: search.ipindia.gov.in/IPOJournal/Journal/Trademark
but unable to get it. If I search for this https://search.ipindia.gov.in/IPOJournal/Journal/ViewJournal/ipo-docs\IPIndia_Docs\TMR\2024\2159\CLASS 1 - 25.pdf link also it shows error.
Could you please help me in finding the pdf urls in python or simply the pdf link how it is structured or where I can view the complete pdf.

I am trying to find the pdf link from this site: but unable to get it - Your question is not clear. Edit your question and start by adding your code trials, the error/exception which you are facing. Also, clearly explain what is it that you are trying to achieve.

the direct link can't be used since the download is initiated by a button element. Looking into the API calls (network tab), the button is using HTTP POST method.
Here is a simple script which downloads the pdf mentioned in your question. And it's easy to expand it according to your needs.
import requests

url = 'https://search.ipindia.gov.in/IPOJournal/Journal/ViewJournal'
data = {'FileName': r'ipo-docs\IPIndia_Docs\TMR\2024\2159\CLASS 1 - 25.pdf'}

req = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False)

with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(req.content)

